# Extjs store.load not working

Tags: extjs

I'm getting from php an `json` encoded

```
{
     "employees": [{
         "Employee_ID": "1",
         "Department_ID": "2",
         "Name": "Bagio",
         "Email": "bagio@gmail.com"
     }, {
         "Employee_ID": "2",
         "Department_ID": "2",
         "Name": "Sinchan",
         "Email": "sinchan@gmail.com"
     }]
 }
```

When I try to load it I get no response. This is my ExtJs 4.2 code

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('Person', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'Employee_ID', 'Department_ID', 'Name', 'Email'
        ]
    });

    // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'Person',
        autoLoad: true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory',
            url: 'example.php',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                root: 'employees'
            }
        }
    });
    store.load();
    Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [{
                text: "Employ_id",
                width: 120,
                dataIndex: 'Employee_ID'
            },
            {
                text: "Department_ID",
                width: 380,
                dataIndex: 'Department_ID'
            },
            {
                text: "Name",
                width: 380,
                dataIndex: 'Name'
            },
            {
                text: "Email",
                width: 380,
                dataIndex: 'Email'
            }
        ],
        renderTo: 'example-grid',
        width: 500,
        height: 280
    });
});
```

Comment: relation to php?

Comment: i'm loading data from mysql while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    
    $myInventory["employees"][$counter] = array(
        'Employee_ID' => $row['Employee_ID'],
        'Department_ID' => $row['Department_ID'],
        'Name' => $row['Name'],
        'Email' => $row['Email']);
    $counter++;
}

$myData = $myInventory;
echo json_encode($myData);
?>

Comment: if this is a php/db related issue, edit your question http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44000454/edit with code and not be dropped in comments; *thank you*

Comment: i don't have problem with php i have problem with extjs

Comment: the php tag has been removed. Only use tags that are related to the problem. In using tags not relevant to the problem, is both unclear and misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the store's proxy type from `memory` to `ajax`. Memory proxy usually is for data that will be loaded from the client session itself, not from a remote source.